# Nginx is not able to server my html files

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Basic html is showing , when i am trying to serve my new folder it is throwing web page not found page.

I have my files inside sample folder which is located in my Documents folders

I am running on windows10

```
location /{
    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;
}

location /myapp/ {
    alias ../Users/Jonn/Documents/sample;
    index  sample.html sample.htm;
}
```

when i access

```
localhost:9090/
```

it is showing welcome page, but when i access localhost:9090/myapp/

it is throwing web page not found

what can i do to server my htmls and images under sample folder.

Comment: Add a space between "location /" and "{". Also specify an absolute path for the `root` keyword.

Comment: for the `alias` can you give the absolute path?

Comment: @Ntwobike yes absolute path is working